# Increase java heap size, using eclipse in windows

Tags: java, memory, error-handling, out-of-memory, heap-size

I am writing a java program to generate first 50 million prime numbers (sieve of eratosthenes) using eclipse in windows.

```
package first;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class primegen {
private static int[] generatePrimes(int max) {
    boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[max + 1];
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= max; i++) {
        if (!isComposite [i]) {
            for (int j = i; i * j <= max; j++) {
                isComposite [i*j] = true;
            }
        }
    }
    int numPrimes = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
        if (!isComposite [i]) numPrimes++;
    }
    int [] primes = new int [numPrimes];
    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= max; i++) {
        if (!isComposite [i]) primes [index++] = i;
    }
    return primes;
}

//The following snippet of code is to check the heapsize
public static void main(String[] args) {
           long heapsize=Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory();
       System.out.println("heapsize is::"+heapsize);

      System.out.println(generatePrimes(982451653)[4]);

   }
}
```

The output for the heap space is:

```
heapsize is::66584576
```

It gives the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at first.primegen.generatePrimes(primegen.java:7)
at first.primegen.main(primegen.java:30)
```

I found out that there is some -xmx command for JVM.
Where do I enter that command and what should be the appropriate size of heap I should set using that command?

I have 4 GB of RAM on my machine (64-bit Windows 7)

Comment: If you use BitSet instead of a `boolean[]` it will use 1/8th of the memory.  I also suggest you use the 64-bit version of Java as this defaults to using 1/4 of your memory i.e. 2 GB maximum instead of 64 MB maximum which the 32-bit windows client JVM does.

Comment: BTW, You can't print the primes as a String this way as a String is limited to 2 billion characters and you need more than this to print all the primes. A String 2 bn characters requires 8 GB of memory to create. You will need at least 4 bytes per `int` value and you don't have enough memory.  I suggest you scan the `BitSet` and print all the values as you find them as this only needs < 200 bytes at a time.

Comment: I have no idea what BitSet is.
Also, I shall not be printing this array. I would just need this array to exist so that I can access any prime number stored in this array.
I will edit my question.

Comment: I suggest you have a look at the documentation for http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html Its a standard library which uses one bit per value instead of 8 bits per value.  As you are building such a large array for your machine, you should make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Open `Eclipse`,  `Window -> Preferences`

Search for `Installed Jre`, must be pointed to you `JDK`.

Edit the same and enter `Default VM arguments` as below or according to your requirement.

```
-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Below psudo code for you to start with

```
private static BitSet generatePrimes(int max) {
        BitSet sieve = new BitSet(max);
        int size = sieve.size();

        for (int i = 2 ; i < size ; i++)
            sieve.set(i);

        int finalBit = (int) Math.sqrt(size);

        for (int i = 2 ; i < finalBit ; i++) {
            if (sieve.get(i)) {
                for (int j = 2 * i ; j < size ; j += i)
                    sieve.clear(j);
            }
        }

        return sieve;
    }
```

Comment: When I write `-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m` in the Default VM arguments section and then run the program with the print statement being `System.out.println(generatePrimes(472882027)[4])`; it returns the following:

`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option     MaxPermSize=512m; support was removed in 8.0`

Comment: But it does give 11, which is the expected output.
Note that the above number is 25th million prime, the program still gives the `OutofMemory` error for 50th million prime.

Comment: For the pseudo code you have mentioned, is `sieve` an array of primes till `int max` ?

Comment: Than you can run and verify, you were not clear on the use of BitSet, so i gave you sample code, but might require few modifications. But yes BitSet occupies less memory compare to boolean, so please make use of it. Also start accepting the answers to get more viewers